# icacls granting access to all users on windows 7

Tags: windows, access-control-list

I'm trying to give full access (read, write) to a specific folder to all users on Windows 7. The problem is that I don't know how to do that using icacls.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
c:\windows\system32\icacls c:\folder /grant "domain\user":(OI)(CI)M
c:\windows\system32\icacls c:\folder /grant "everyone":(OI)(CI)M
c:\windows\system32\icacls c:\folder /grant "Authenticated Users":(OI)(CI)M
```

Open command window and type `c:\windows\system32\icacls /?`

Comment: +1.  Depending on context, (OI)(CI)F (full access) might be preferable to (OI)(CI)M (read/write access).

Comment: Alas, cut and paste fom one of my scripts :-)
M = Modify which is fine for most users, F will give them everything

Comment: Note that you will NOT be able to use "everyone" and other groups on localized Windows (English names are only available on English Windows). So you might want to use one of SID (e.g. "everyone" is "*S-1-1-0" -- take note of the use of use star before SID) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330

Comment: Issuing icacls *.* /t /grant "everyone": (OI) (CI) F returns "Invalid parameter "everyone:""

Comment: @Bobo The OP requested full access. Your answer needs to be that. You can suggest Modify in the answer as well if you think it's appropriate.

Comment: The options for icacls do not run easily under PowerShell, because brackets ( ) have a special meaning in PowerShell, to pass a bracket symbol to an external program it must be escaped with a backtick.
Alternatively, use the stop-parsing symbol --%
e.g.: `icacls "C:\demo\" --% /grant *S-1-1-0:(OI)(CI)F /T`

Answer (score 6):

Only [these](https://superuser.com/a/354674/103551) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311008/819417) answers worked for me:

In an Administrator Command Prompt:

```
C:\Windows\System32>takeown /r /d y /f f:\backup
C:\Windows\System32>icacls f:\backup /t /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F
```

`(OI)` is for future files and `(CI)` for future folders.

Comment: `icacls "f:\backup" /grant Everyone:(f)` worked for me. Using `(OE)`, and `(CI)` were not working for me although the command was showing success. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Step 1 - Open cmd window with admin privileges

Step 2 - to take ownership of contents of "picts" directory
         takeown /f C:\picts* /r

Step 3 - to change permissions to "everyone" of contents of "picts" directory
         icacls C:\picts /grant Everyone:F /t

Answer (score 1):

Open administrator command prompt. And run

```
grantAccess.cmd FOLDER_PATH
```

where FOLDER_PATH can be:

- "d:" - for change whole drive
- "d:\somefolder" - for change folder

grantAccess.cmd file content is:

```
@echo off

rem FOLDER_PATH can be "d:" or "d:\somefolder"

set FOLDER_PATH=%1

echo taking ownership...
takeown /F "%FOLDER_PATH%" /R /D Y /SKIPSL
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

set SUBELEMENTS=/L /T /C
set QUIET=/Q
set USERNAME=*S-1-1-0

echo setting access rights for the root folder
icacls "%FOLDER_PATH%" /inheritance:r /grant:r "%USERNAME%":(OI)(CI)F
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

echo reset access rights for childs
ICACLS "%FOLDER_PATH%\\*" /reset %SUBELEMENTS% %QUIET%
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

echo change owner
icacls "%FOLDER_PATH%" /setowner "%USERNAME%" %SUBELEMENTS% %QUIET%
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

:success
echo SUCCESS!!!
EXIT /B 0
:error
echo ERROR!!!
EXIT /B 1
```